# ubuntu pc freezes and reboots

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the computer which is brand new and worked very well so far which now randomly freezes (freezes completely no mouse movement nothing) and then reboots after a few seconds of being freezed.

Log files show nothing:

```
May  8 16:40:44 malmignatta whoopsie[1062]: online
May  8 16:42:02  whoopsie[1062]: last message repeated 2 times
May  8 17:09:01 malmignatta CRON[7057]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
May  8 17:17:01 malmignatta CRON[7167]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="774" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta bluetoothd[748]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta bluetoothd[748]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.11.0-19-generic (buildd@comet) (gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) ) #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 18:48:34 UTC 2014 (Ubuntu 3.11.0-19.33-generic 3.11.10.5)
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic root=UUID=02da4203-ebce-4ff4-ab30-bf6d860d1262 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
May  8 17:18:54 malmignatta kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
```

The reboot in the above file happened at 17:17:00, no hint as to what happened.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details regarding this.  There's not enough info to really help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Found out, it was a wire which had moved inside the case stopping the graphic's card fan!!

Now I hope it didn't damage the graphics, anyway strange that in the log up there there's no trace of the graphic card telling the pc to stop and reboot!